# Why is Allen Ginsberg's "Howl" dedicated to Carl Solomon specifically?

Tags: poetry, allen-ginsberg, carl-solomon

The poem "Howl" by Allen Ginsberg ([which can be read online](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/49303/howl)) is partly a savage general commentary on society and partly an expression of solidarity for the institutionalised fellow writer Carl Solomon.

Part I of the poem describes [many writers and artists of the time, with whom Ginsberg was acquainted](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/1131/17) - including, but not only, Carl Solomon. Part II is a [dark vision of society](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/1633/17) - a rant about the evil and despair Ginsberg saw all around him. Part III is entirely addressed to Carl Solomon, every line beginning with "I’m with you in Rockland" (Rockland being a mental asylum where Solomon was kept).

My question is: **why was Solomon so special to Ginsberg?** Obviously they knew each other and Ginsberg sympathised with Solomon's plight, but he also knew many of the other unfortunate suffering souls referred to in Part I - what made this particular one more worthy of an ode than the rest?

Comment: See some info [here](http://beatbabble.blogspot.com/2013/01/investigating-carl-solomon-from.html).